# What's the best way to verify XML signature in python?

Tags: python, xml, pycrypto, xml-signature, pyopenssl

I'm trying to validate XML message signature with given public key in Python which is validated fine on a PHP code with openssl.

Here's PHP code that's working fine.

```
$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents("public_key.pem"));

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("message.xml");

$signedInfo=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("SignedInfo")->item(0)->C14N(true, true);
$signature = base64_decode($xmlDoc->documentElement->getElementsByTagName("SignatureValue")->item(0)->nodeValue);

$ok = openssl_verify($signedInfo, $signature, $pubKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
```

I've found different libraries in Python to achieve this but none of them are verifying fine. I've listed the libraries and the problems I've faced on. Is there any other preferred ways to achieve this?

**1. pyOpenSSL**

It fails with following message: [('rsa routines', 'INT_RSA_VERIFY', 'wrong signature length')]

```
import OpenSSL.crypto as c
from StringIO import StringIO
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml_et
from myapp import settings

namespace = "{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}"

xml_bytes = open(settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/file/test.xml', 'rt').read()
response_xml = xml_et.fromstring(xml_bytes.encode('utf-8'))
signature_elem = response_xml.find(namespace + 'Signature')
signature_value = signature_elem.find(namespace + 'SignatureValue').text

signed_info_output = StringIO()
signed_info_tree = xml_et.ElementTree(signature_elem.find(namespace + 'SignedInfo'))
signed_info_tree.write_c14n(signed_info_output)
signed_info = signed_info_output.getvalue()

# load certificate
cert = c.load_certificate(c.FILETYPE_PEM, open(settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/file/public.cert', 'rt').read())

# verify signature
try:
    c.verify(cert, signature_value, signed_info, 'sha1')
    print 'success'
except Exception, e:
    print 'fail'
```

**2. M2Crypto**

Tried to install M2Crypto but it fails with cannot find openssl/err.h header file. So I've installed openssl 1.1.0e and copied lib and include directories to C:/pkg directory and it throws different error like:
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(3754) : error C2065: 'CRYPTO_NUM_LOCKS' : undeclared ident ifier
And found precompiled M2Crypto msi installer but during runtime it throws following error:
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

This library seems outdated and not enough documentation available.

**3. signxml**

So far it's the only library that works partially for me.
Xml verification works fine but it throws error on sign: ValueError: Could not unserialize key data.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier
from myapp import settings

cert = open(settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/file/public.cert', 'rt').read()
key = open(settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/file/public.key', 'rt').read()

root = ElementTree.fromstring('<xml1>12</xml1>')
signed_root = XMLSigner().sign(root, key=key, cert=cert)
verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(signed_root).signed_xml
print verified_data
```

Comment: Signatures contain arbitrary bytes and so need to converted to readable characters. You do base64 decoding in PHP, but  apparently nothing equivalent in Python. Take at look at the base64 (or binascii) module.

Comment: The signature part doesn't contain any bytes, it has base64 encoded string. For example: g1+4I5jTQWMUezyATWqUkdE6el4ewrx4WuRsDhXzlEM2hvZR3UoXBPCICfpyJOdlmvu9c3KI
V3Pps59vajMCimCQpxm3r6+TOqTUNrWGrYeyZr1U5ayK0nNXQZ17c/+bbRwaL5r0i725R7bu
5vUW+ZPrlfOkbvMXkJ5YWg5yVSzeuux9ih3JpYcKCsZA90oEjYNqcH0LnzEy/BC04p8HMMY1
vrISXfHcy4ZmpLPhPMz5uf6rG+o4bIbhhWyDIiHVcaT1ejLCg1NKC/BDK+u2te9XhBSxXp6R
r59Jhu2gIh/JOEjBzaTGrNdW7P4CRUFxpRTPeOreTLfPryXV+dReuA==

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question in the title is `signxml`.

It is the library designed for the stated purpose. `PyOpenSSL` and `M2Crypto` operate on lower-level objects than XML signature; verifying the latter would involve canonicalizing XML, digesting proper parts of it, and comparing the provided signature over the digest. While possible, this is not trivial and provides much space for errors. For example in your code for `PyOpenSSL` you do not base64-decode the signature value.

With `signxml`, your example is mostly correct. For verification of the signature, you do not need the private key, so the error you get is not relevant to the question. You should in general read the certificate and the key in binary, not text mode (`open(filename, "rb")`) - even if the files are PEM-encoded.

The following is a working example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier

cert = open("cert.pem", "rb").read()
key = open("key.pem", "rb").read()

xml_obj = ElementTree.fromstring("<Example/>")
signed_xml_obj = XMLSigner().sign(xml_obj, key=key)
XMLVerifier().verify(signed_xml_obj, x509_cert=cert)
```

If your XML object has been serialized and de-serialized after signing, this simplest code might be not enough; the (complicated) details are described [here](https://technotes.shemyak.com/posts/xml-signatures-with-python-elementtree/).